# How can I start with <a href=" and have an array element here then end with </a>?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, image

The thing im trying to do right now is pulling in multiple  links from a textarea,

We can pretend that a user inputs c:\pics\img01.jpg and in the next row he'll have the next imglink.

I want to pull those links, I allready have the code for that:

```
var entered = $('#filedir').val();  
var lines = entered.split(/\r\n/);  
var opttext = "";  
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {  
    opttext += '< img src="' + lines[i] + '">< /img>';
}
​
```

the problem is in the output which is:

```
< img src="file:///C:/pics/img01.jpgc:/pics/img02.jpg">< /img>
```

There should be two `< img>` elements..

Where am I going wrong?
I've been at it for a bit over 2 hours now..

Comment: What makes you think that the "lines" string starts off with a cr-lf (carriage return - newline) pair in it? Maybe it's just a newline ("\n")

Comment: make sure var lines.length is actually 2 ..

Comment: IE gives you CRLFs in `textarea.value`. Other browsers don't. So you'd need to split on `/\r?\n/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your lines aren't getting split correctly and you're ending up with one long line in the array. Try this instead:

```
var lines = entered.split(/\n/);
```

Comment: Solved it!

omg.. 2+ hours and all that was wrong was two characters..

Thanks!!

Comment: @David I did, it told me to wait 2 minutes.. just waited for it.. a bit too long i guess :p :)! thanks though

Comment: "this\r\nis\na\rtest".split(/\r?\n|\r/)  \r for old mac, \n for linux/osx, \r\n for windows... sample above works for all three.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
{
     opttext += '<img src="' + lines[i] + '"></img>';
}
```

Your `for` loop was incorrect.

Comment: .. i think its the same, i had to put the space between < img to make the thread allow me to write it out.. don't know how to do it otherwise, but thanks!